# Assigning an allocated object to some non allocated object can cause the memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Is my following code contains a memory leak?
please help me here!

```
NSMutableArray *arrInfo =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
appDelegate.arrAppInfo = arrInfo;
[arrInfo release];
```

Comment: why do you think it contains a memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is perfectly valid in a non-ARC environment IF the property arrAppInfo is declared as a retain (or strong) property. In fact what ARC does in a similar situation is just putting a release when it detect that the arrInfo property is no longer used in the current scope.

To go deep:

```
NSMutableArray *arrInfo =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //arrInfo retain count = 1
appDelegate.arrAppInfo = arrInfo; //arrInfo retain count = 2
[arrInfo release]; //arrInfo retain count = 1
```

If you weren't releasing the arrInfo variable after assigning it to a retained property you would have caused a memory leak in the future when reassigning or releasing the arrAppInfo property, since its retain count wouldn't be 0.

Comment: I have declared it as follows @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrAppInfo; in appDelegate class

Comment: So the code you posted is valid and memory leak free, you should accept this as a valid answer

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how arrAppInfo is defined in appDelegate.

If its a strong reference, this would be good as long as appDelegate releases arrAppInfo at some point.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrAppInfo; //All good
```

If its a weak reference, then you will get an error when you try to access arrAppInfo because its been released.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *arrAppInfo; //Trouble
```